# Is scala native garbage collector compatible with C interoperability?

Tags: c, garbage-collection, function-pointers, scala-native

I wonder when Zone or stack allocation are necessary when using C interoperability. For instance, if I call C function which takes function pointer, can I use any Scala function (with conversion to CFuncPtr)? Or must I use only Scala function with stack allocated objects ou zoned memory?